How to print page number to other language in Jasper Report by Jaspersoft Studio?
In Jaspersoft Studio, I generating my jasper report. So now i want to print page numbers in the report to other language. I can't found actual solution yet.
Right now, I'm using "পৃষ্ঠাঃ "+ $V{PAGE_NUMBER} in Jaspersoft Studio, here generating page numbers such as: পৃষ্ঠাঃ 1, পৃষ্ঠাঃ 2, পৃষ্ঠাঃ 3, etc. where page numbers are English Digits. But i want to other language.

Why down vote in my question, anyone knows?

As from your question I can understand you want to change it to bengali digit,
If you setup localization then you can achieve it through localization I guess, if not then there is a shortcut you can apply to change the page number english to bengali,
"পৃষ্ঠাঃ "+ $V{PAGE_NUMBER}.toString().replaceAll("0", "০")
       .replaceAll("1", "১")
       .replaceAll("2", "২")
       .replaceAll("3", "৩")
       .replaceAll("4", "৪")
       .replaceAll("5", "৫")
       .replaceAll("6", "৬")
       .replaceAll("7", "৭")
       .replaceAll("8", "৮")
       .replaceAll("9", "৯")

Let me know if it helps you

Yeah, This technique worked for me.
